# Изменение изображения при нажатии

Tags: html, css

Привет всем! Хочу на сайте реализовать такую функцию. У меня есть две картинки кнопки регистрации. Одна просто, а вторая "нажатая". Как сделать так, что бы при нажатии на image.gif, отобразилось image2.gif. При этом так же при нажатии открывалась страница reger.php.

Comment: поздравляем =)

Comment: Не совсем ясен Ваш комментарий.

Comment: @Александр Гижевский: смею думать, это была ирония :) Вы пишете "нужно сделать". Очевидно, нужно не нам, а вам. Вы бы сформулировали конкретный вопрос. Полностью весь код за вас никто писать скорее всего не захочет, а вот ответить на какой-нибудь технический вопрос многие смогли бы.

Comment: Думаю, что так лучше.

Comment: Эм..

    .register-super-button:active { background..

Оно?

Comment: При клике менять src картинки, либо если у вас картинка как фон, то менять background

Comment: <img src="/reg_button1.gif" onclick="this.src='/reg_button.gif'"> 
Попробовал так. Но не отображается картинка.

Comment: Google уже изобрели. [Вот][1].


  [1]: https://www.google.ru/search?q=html+%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так у меня работает:

```
<img src='1.png' onclick="this.src='2.png'">
```

Вы учитываете, что `/reg_bottom.gif` - это абсолютный адрес ссылки?
Вот так, если хотите, чтобы возвращалась первая картинка после нажатия

```
<img src='1.png' onmousedown="this.src='2.png'" onmouseup="this.src='1.png'">
```

Comment: <img src='reg_button1.gif' onmousedown="this.src='reg_button.gif'" onmouseup="this.src='reg_button1.gif'">

Вот так сделал, но все равно не отображается картинка.